# Is CoreData appropriate for saving information daily and some information permanently?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

As of right now, I have almost completed my application where a user can set the daily calorie goals, and add foods to their daily calorie progress. However, I now want to make my application save the daily calorie progress until the day ends, but keep the information about the users calorie goal permantly until they change it. My question being, should I use coreData for this, as I have not set it up before the project was made. If anyone has any suggestions please let me know :)

Also these are my models which are environment objects:

```
import Foundation

class UserInfoModel: ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared: UserInfoModel = UserInfoModel() // <<: Here

    struct UserInfo: Identifiable {
        var id = UUID()
        var firstName: String
        var height: Double
        var weight: Double
        var gender: String
        var age: Double
        var activityLevel: String
        var BMR: Double
    
struct DailyCalorieGoals: Identifiable{
        var id = UUID()
        var calorieGoal: Double
        var fatGoal: Double
        var proteinGoal: Double
        var carbGoal: Double

    }
    
    struct CurrentCalorieProgress: Identifiable{
        var id = UUID()
        var calorieProgress: Double
        var fatProgress: Double
        var carbProgress: Double
        var proteinProgress: Double

    }



 @Published var personUserInfo = UserInfo.init(firstName: "",  height: 0, weight: 0, gender: "", age: 0, activityLevel: "", BMR: 0)
    @Published var personDailyCalorieGoals = DailyCalorieGoals.init(calorieGoal: 2400, fatGoal: 40, proteinGoal: 40, carbGoal: 40)
    @Published var personCurrentCalorieProgress = CurrentCalorieProgress.init(calorieProgress: 1200, fatProgress:   12, carbProgress: 5, proteinProgress: 30)
    
    @Published var  recipeNutrientsSearch = SearchRecipeCalories.init(fat: 0, carb: 0, protein: 0)
    

}
```

Comment: To me this looks like something you could store in a file instead rather than using a complex solution like Core Data. If you use JSON and the Codable protocol the implementation should be quite easy.

Comment: What's the point of users inputting their daily calorie intake if it's just going to be deleted the next day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question being, should I use coreData for this

Lets answer this question with the process of elimination.

You said:

> However, I now want to make my application save the daily calorie progress until the day ends

- UserDefaults. No because  `UserDefaults` is for a small finite amount of information. Any data that *grows* should not be stored there. Although this is perhaps the easiest method to save, its an unfit solution here.
- Networking. Your call. But more than likely no. Its a little too complex for such as simple task and may lead to bad user experience not to mention unnecessary maintenance and/or third party involvements.
- Creating your own SQL Database, again its your call but why go through this unnecessary complexity when CoreData was created for this very purpose.

**CoreData** is the clear winner here. Quick, user friendly (once you get the hang of it) and Apple seems to care for this framework a lot so no need to worry about future deprecations. You can read more about CoreData [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata)

Comment: After doing some research, I opted for this information too. But thank you for breaking down the other options!

Answer (score 0):

this data i think is a log data for your customers that you might have later use for it. in my opinion use a simple elasticSearch installation server-side and locally save data in userDefaults for about 100 logs and then upload them to server and remove them locally. a good thing about this is all the options elasticSearch would give you and ES rest api's which is very simple to use and you could get very interesting insights about how customers log data and how you can change it.

Comment: one thing about saving a lot of data locally without providing an api to delete them is the risk of your app being deleted or offloaded.